# How to exclude a folder from Laravel route?

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, authentication, routes

I am currently working on a laravel 5.6 project. Here I have uploaded and extracted zip file in the 'public/uploads/games' directory (extracted files contains html, css, js files). Now I want to give access to this folder only to the authenticated user. So, I have included a route in routes/web.php. Here is my route:

```
Route::get('uploads', function() {
    echo 'hello';
});
```

But, as because I have a folder named 'uploads', this routing isn't working. I need this route to check authentication. I'll implement the middleware later.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What  error you are getting ? Share your all routes above from this route.

Answer (score 0):

The Apache checks if `uploads` is a folder before call `index.php`.

You can remove `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` from your `.htaccess` file, but is not the better solution.

For you protect a public folder or public file you need to use your web server, but is more complex.

I suggest that you maintain your uploads folder in storage path with private access and create a route like this:

```
Route::get('uploads/{filename}', function ($filename) {
    return file_get_contents(
        storage_path('some-private-uploads-folder/' . $filename)
    );
});
```

This implementation is basic, but can helps you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have uploaded the .htaccess file and if your rewrite rule is switched on.
If it works it should ignore every files and directories expecting you index.php file.
I'm sure it is not working properly.